# Tar a list of files which don't all exist

Tags: shell, wildcards, tar

I'm running a command from a script like

```
tar -c -f ar.tar a b c d
```

where b, c, and d may not exist, and may be directories. The solutions that I've come up with are piping the output of `ls -d` to `grep`, then splicing it into the `tar` command, or turning on extended globs for `@(a|b|c|d)`.

Is there a neater way of doing this? I'm on Debian Wheezy, which doesn't seem to have an `--include` parameter.

Comment: Do you have `--ignore-failed-read` option?

Comment: Tried it, still gave an error for files which don't exist at all.

Comment: Yes, error message is present but archive is created.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try

```
 tar cf ar.tar $(ls a b c d )
```

where

- `c` for create
- `f ar.tar` specify tar file
- `$(ls a b c d)` will list to stdin which file are realy present (and give error for other)

Comment: `tar cf ar.tar $(ls -d a b c d 2>/dev/null)` works perfectly .. but I think it's cleaner with extglob

Comment: now I'm porting the script to dash, so no `extglob` - I'm using the code in my comment above

Answer (score 3):

If it is ok to have the full path of the files in the tar archive you can do:

```
tar -c -f ar.tar $(readlink -e a b c d)
```

The `-e` option to readlink will canonicalize existing filenames and silently ignore any others.

Comment: I guess that might work if I `--strip-components` while extracting.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
find path/to/dir -name "*.ext1" -o -name "*.ext2"
```

**Explanation**

1. The first parameter is the directory you want to search.
2. By default `find` does recursion.
3. The `-o` stands for `-or`. So above means search for this wildcard OR this one. If you have only one pattern then no need for `-o`.
4. The quotes around the wildcard pattern are required.